# Считать два файла одновременно

Tags: c#

Как через массив считать два файла одновременно и показать текст файлов на экране через пробел?

```
string[] masiv1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text1.txt");
string[] masiv2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text2.txt");

foreach (var line1 in masiv1)
{
    foreach (var line2 in masiv2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line1 + " " + line2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Считайте их поочереди в массив строк и покажите. Не надо делать цикл в цикле, вы так второй файл будите считывать, столько раз сколько строк в первом файле...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью `for`

```
string[] masiv1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text1.txt");
string[] masiv2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text2.txt");

// Если одинаковое количество строк
for (int i = 0; i < masiv1.Length; i++)
{  
    Console.WriteLine(masiv1[i] + " " + masiv2[i]);
}    

// Если разное количество строк
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(masiv1.Length, masiv2.Length); i++)
{
    var line1 = i < masiv1.Length ? masiv1[i] : string.Empty;
    var line2 = i < masiv2.Length ? masiv2[i] : string.Empty;

    Console.WriteLine(line1 + " " + line2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для таких вещей обычно используют `Zip`:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text1.txt");
IEnumerable<string> lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text2.txt");

foreach (var combinedLine in lines1.Zip(lines2, (l1, l2) => l1 + " " + l2))
    Console.WriteLine(combinedLine);
```